# Build scroller in nodejs

Tags: node.js, scroll

I want to build a scroller in nodeJS, that will give me specific element's value of  a webpage.

I don't know how it works, but I think something like this:

```
let title = await Scroll.get(url).contain('div#main h1#title').innerHTML
```

I saw such things in JS, but I want to do that in the server.

Answer (score 0):

It's me again... 
I've found an answer to my problem.

You can do this to get the whole page

```
const request = require("request");

let options = {
    uri: `www.google.com` 
}

request(options,(error, response, body) => {
    if(error) throw(error);
    console.log(body);
});
```

You can also use it like a promise :

```
function getWebpage(uri){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = {
            uri: uri
        }
        request(options,(error, response, body) => {
            if(error) reject(error);            
            resolve(body);
        });
    });
}

getWebpage('www.google.com')
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Note : From what I've seen, you have to get the entire webpage. If you saw else, I'd happy to know